# Linq to SQL query with COALESCE in where clause

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am trying to convert the following sql query in to linq to sql (for entity framework)

```
  select A.*, B.* from TABLE1 A
                   left join TABLE2 B
                  on A.LocationLoadPositionId = B.FkLocationLoadPositionId
                  where COALESCE(B.UploadStatus,0) = 0
```

So far I've got it to this far:

```
var positions = (from a in dbContext.TABLE1 join b in dbContext.TABLE2
                   on a.LocationLoadPositionId equals b.FkLocationLoadPositionId into c from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where d.UploadStatus == false select new { a, d }).ToList();
```

The above linq query doens't seem to be working correctly because of my where condition... I am getting different result set for the two queries above... what am i missing here?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var positions = (from a in dbContext.TABLE1 join b in dbContext.TABLE2
                   on a.LocationLoadPositionId equals b.FkLocationLoadPositionId into c from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where d.UploadStatus == false || d == null select new { a, d }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Somethings like..

```
var positions = (from a in dbContext.TABLE1
                 join b in dbContext.TABLE2
                 on a.LocationLoadPositionId equals b.FkLocationLoadPositionId into c
                 let x = d.UploadStatus == 0 //<--- COALESCE
                 from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where x == true).ToList();
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: i am getting an error with the above query you have provided...

Comment: please copy and paste here